# PHP - Eclipse PDT - Highlighting uinitialized (misspelled) variables

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

I use the wonderful Eclipse PDT for PHP development.

I often encounter irritating bugs due to me misspelling variable names.

Is there a way to highlight variables that have not been initialized? As they will almost certainly be due to a spelling mistake.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Just make sure you write small functions/methods.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Due to the dynamic, sometimes hackish nature of PHP, it would overall be a pain to have variables that the IDE thinks is undeclared be underlined. Since many functions can declare variables on their own (such as [extract](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.extract.php)), this would be a major hindrance.

Answer (score 2):

zend studio has this feature so i'm not sure if we'll see it in pdt, it will also highlight unreachable code, etc.

Answer (score 1):

JEdit with PHPParser plugin had that, IIRC. It's been long since I tried it, though, I might be wrong.